# How to get a filepath and file name from a string of contents?

Tags: javascript

How can I get just get the file path and file name from a string?

My string looks like the following

```
GET /content/random.gif HTTP/1.0
```

I tried the regex `^(.+)/([^/]+)$`, but it didn't work. Is there an alternative to regex?

Comment: Just split the string on the spaces. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: if every string will share that same format then you can use `string.split(' ')[1]`.

Comment: Thanks!! i completely forgot about split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to extend the comments of using a string split. To get the filepath and filename you could use the following:

```js
var str = 'GET /content/random.gif HTTP/1.0';
var file = str.split(' ')[1];
var filepath = file.substr( 0,file.lastIndexOf('/')+1 );
var filename = file.substr( file.lastIndexOf('/')+1 );

console.log('filepath: '+filepath);
console.log('filename: '+filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short, simple and reliable

```
var str = 'GET /content/random.gif HTTP/1.0';
var re = /^.+? (.*)\/([^\/]*) .+?$/;
var m = str.match(re);

var filepath = m[1];
var filename = m[2];
```